# Set timestamps to microseconds in Phoenix with MySQL

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I’m running into a problem using Phoenix 1.2, ecto 2.1.4, mariaex 0.8.2, mysql 5.6.33 — I want to store the timestamps in microseconds, but the column created by the `timestamps/1` function is a standard `datetime`, which rounds to seconds. In [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1) they mention a `usec` option for timestamps, but even explicitly setting this to true isn't changing the table.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [undocumented option](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/pull/2013/files) for the `timestamps/1` function: `size`. So `timestamps(size: 6)` will set the database column to a `datetime(6)`.

---

In more recent versions of Ecto, there is a dedicated [usec](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/ed861cbbfae1907463304597ee44d0951f9d0946/lib/ecto/adapters/mysql.ex) type, [described here](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/b22cb7ca4f260b71f694ce570f72dfe1245dd22f/lib/ecto/type.ex).

Comment: Has this been changed to `usec` now? Cause I did try it and it didn't work, not sure if it's because this is a recent change.

Comment: what versions of everything are you using?

Comment: I would try using the 'type' option for timestamps and setting it to one of the usec types.

Comment: `timestamps(type: :utc_datetime_usec)` works fine (Elixir 1.7.4, Phoenix 1.4)